# What best way to include dll for tdbc::mysql&tdbc::postgres under windows starpack?

Tags: mysql, windows, postgresql, tcl, tdbc

Packages tdbc::mysql and tdbc::postgresql require dll libmysql.dll and libpq.dll somewere in PATH. What best way to include this dlls into single starpack?

For now I'm using following pkgIndex.tcl:

```
if {[catch {package require Tcl 8.6}]} {
    return
}
package ifneeded tdbc::postgres 1.0.0 [list apply {{dir} {
  if { $::tcl_platform(os) eq "Windows NT" &&
        ($::tcl_platform(machine) eq "intel" || 
         $::tcl_platform(machine) ne "amd64") } {
    foreach n {libpq libeay32 ssleay32 comerr32 gssapi32 
               k5sprt32 krb5_32 libiconv-2 libintl-8} {     
      file copy -force [file join $dir ${n}.dll] \
        [file join $::env(WINDIR) System32 ${n}.dll]
    }
  }
  source [file join $dir tdbcpostgres.tcl]
  load [file join $dir tdbcpostgres100.dll] tdbcpostgres
}} $dir]
```

But this looks very ugly.

I was trying to find a way to copy the necessary libraries to the temporary folder used by the interpreter to load dll.  But by examining the Tcl source code, find out the name of the temporary directory is not possible for script.

**update:** At the current time, I decided to use twapi to determine the name of the temporary folder that is used by the Tcl interpreter. I get the following code:

```
if {[catch {package require Tcl 8.6}]} {
    return
}
package ifneeded tdbc::postgres 1.0.0 [list apply {{dir} {
  if { $::tcl_platform(os) eq "Windows NT" &&
        ($::tcl_platform(machine) eq "intel" || 
         $::tcl_platform(machine) eq "amd64") } {
    package require twapi
    set _ [file dirname [lindex [lsearch -inline -index 1 -glob \
          [twapi::get_process_modules [twapi::get_current_process_id] -path] \
          {*/twapi_base*.dll}] 1]]
    if { $_ eq "." } { 
      error "couldn't find temp folder name for tdbc::postgres support library" 
    }
    foreach fn [glob -types f -tails -directory $dir "*.dll"] {
      if { [string match -nocase "tdbcpostgres*" $fn] } continue
      file copy -force [file join $dir $fn] [file join $_ $fn]
    }
  } {
    set _ [pwd]
  }
  source [file join $dir tdbcpostgres.tcl]
  set tpwd [pwd]
  cd $_
  catch { load [file join $dir tdbcpostgres100.dll] tdbcpostgres } r o
  cd $tpwd
  return -options $o $r
}} $dir]
```

But still there was a problem with the removal of temporary files after the program exit. I see only one solution: at the start of the program to scan the folder `$::env(TEMP)` and try to delete all temporary folders that are named as `TCLXXXXXXXX`.

Comment: Depending on the Windows and Tcl version, this might or might not work. On my Windows 7 machine with Tcl 8.6.0 it does not use a temporary directory, instead it loads the stuff from memory. I don't know the exact details how this work.

Answer (score 1):

The "solution" to copy the files to `c:\windows\system32` will not work without administrator access, which most applications starting with Windows Vista don't have. (You'd have to choose "run as admin") And what about newer files in the system32 directory? You just replace them.

Some alternatives:

- Copy all the dlls yourself to a temporary directory, switch to that directory and load the dll (exploits the fact that you look into . as well on windows):

  ```
  package ifneeded tdbc::postgres 1.0.0 [list apply {{dir} {
      set dest [file join $::env(TEMP) tcl[file seconds]]
      file mkdir $dest
      foreach dll [glob -dir $dir *.dll] {
          file copy $dll $dest
      }
      set cwd [pwd]
      cd $dest
      catch {
          source [file join $dir tdbcpostgres.tcl]
          load [file join $dest tdbcpostgres100.dll] tdbcpostgres
      } res opt
      cd $cwd
      return -options $opt $res
  }} $dir]
  ```

  But how should we clean this up?
- Compile the dlls into the starpack. That is hard.
- Compile the extension yourself, so it does not have any dependencies. I don't know how to do that.
- Load each required dll yourself. This is my favorite solution, but it requires twapi:

  ```
  package ifneeded tdbc::postgres 1.0.0 [list apply {{dir} {
      package require twapi
      foreach dll [glob -dir $dir *.dll] {
          ::twapi::load_library $dll
      }
      source [file join $dir tdbcpostgres.tcl]
      load [file join $dir tdbcpostgres100.dll] tdbcpostgres
  }} $dir]
  ```

Comment: Unfortunately, the decision to use twapi not work. The procedure `twapi::load_library` does not support loading from vfs. The solution to create its own temporary folder looks pretty good, but it remains a very important question about clearing the temporary folder.

Comment: I just used it to load something from vfs. I use twapi 4.0b22 through.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem with that trick is that it requires write access to a system directory. You don't want to do that. However, you can instead use the fact that `load` doesn't undo the loading of the library if it fails to find the bootstrap symbol. (This is a variation from Tcl's usual “be as clean as possible in the failure mode” model, but it's damn useful here.)

```
package ifneeded tdbc::postgres 1.0.0 [list apply {{dir} {
    global tcl_platform
    if {$tcl_platform(os) eq "Windows NT" && $tcl_platform(machine) ne "amd64"} {
        foreach n {libpq libeay32 ssleay32 comerr32 gssapi32 
                   k5sprt32 krb5_32 libiconv-2 libintl-8} {
            if {![file exist [file join $::env(WINDIR) System32 ${n}.dll]]} {
                # Leverage Tcl's built-in loading magic
                catch {load [file join $dir ${n}.dll]}
            }
        }
    }
    source [file join $dir tdbcpostgres.tcl]
    load [file join $dir tdbcpostgres100.dll] tdbcpostgres
}} $dir]
```

This is still not very elegant, but intercepting the real dependency loading mechanism is damn hard; pre-loading is just way easier. (I've also stopped the code from doing tricks if the user already has the particular library.)

---

The *proper* fix is to get a build of `tdbcpostgres100.dll` that has those other dependencies as *static* libraries. This is quite a lot of work, I'd guess; I've not tried to do it.

Comment: I tried to use this solution. Unfortunately, it does not work. `Tcl_Loadfile` function immediately deletes the temporary file if the load failed.